# Will "something else" option wipe my hard drive?

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive

I'm using VirtualBox and after testing Ubuntu a bit I decided to download it.

During the installation procedure, it comes up with some options such as *Erase disk and install Ubuntu* and *Something else*. If I select *Something else* it won't erase my hard disk, will it? I'm also using Windows 10.

[image: Heres what it says]

Comment: No, it will not erase your disk just by clicking that option, but you can potentially loose all your data if you don't know what you're doing afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you booted the iso in VirtualBox then the installer is referring to the virtual disk in the virtual machine. In this case, you probably want to select the erase option because the something else option requires more advanced knowledge.

If it was referring to your OS disk, you would see an option to install alongside your other operating system, so you're good to go.